# Eviction of Ignite Cache Entries at particular time and storage to HBASE

Tags: hbase, ignite

I am storing entries in IgniteCache, and After each time interval (lets say 1 Hr), entries stored in that Hour should get Evicted and Stored to Hbase. How can I achieve this?

I tried as follows.

```
setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ONE_HOUR));
```

But this evicts entries one by one, after 1 Hour when particular entry was inserted, I want Bulk eviction and those evicted entries will be stored in HBASE.

Comment: what is eviction policy set?

Comment: Hello, I am using LruEvictionPolicy, can you suggest any other policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to evict everything that you have in cache, right? If so, I would just use [`write-through`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store) to make sure that all the cache updates are propagated to HBASE, and then simply destroy and recreate the cache from scratch every hour.

Comment: Yes I am going to delete every thing from cache, I did use the write-though but it affect one entry that I am inserting, ie the entry inserting in Cache (I am storing entyries in form of JSONObject). I want one complete Eviction of Cache, and all those collective Entries will be evicted on a Listener. In short, I am making Ignite a buffer for entries which are to be inserted in HBASE for 1 hour.

Comment: This will require iteration through all entries in the cache. And (depending on required guarantees) probably lock-the-world semantics during this eviction process. The solution I proposed do not require this - data is written to HBase while you update the cache, and in-memory data is cleared immediately since you can destroy the whole cache (this operation does not require iteration).

Comment: Hello, What happen to evicted data, can I get that evicted data on Any Listener or Method or such